# How to get rid of the tick box (choice) in drop down menu, options, select

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdo

I wish to display quantity and its corresponding discounts as a list, purely as information, without needing for the user to select any of them.
eg. 
1-5,0%
6-10, 5%
11-30,10%
31-90,20%
These information are taken from a sql table, depending on which part number the customer types in, therefore have no way of loading them for selection beforehand, therefore I guess jquery can't help me here.
What I need is to get rid of the tick box,first of all because it is used in a mobile phone platform and space is at a premium and also because there is no need for a tick mark, since the user can't make any choices and is purely used for info.
Am I trying to reinvent the wheel here or is there another option already there and I don't know about it?

```
echo "<td class='basket1'>";
// -----------------price break here --------



    $totq=$row["mqty"];






    // ----- calculate total price ------

    $totp=$row["mqty"]*$row["mpr"];
    $totpr=$totpr+$totp;

//     ====== Find the relevant p-n ==================

$stmt = $pd->prepare('SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE part_number = :part_number'  );
$stmt->execute(array(':part_number' => $row['mpn']));

$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);




        $c=$row["price_each1"];//  price for single item

                             echo "<select name=select>";   
                            for($i = 1; $i <= 8; $i++)
                            {

                            $b=$row["price_each".$i];


                            if ($b !=0.00)
                                {

                                $d=(($c-$b)/$c)*100;

                            $complete=$row[("price_break".$i)]. " ," .round($d)."%";



                            echo "<option> ";
                    echo  $complete ."</option>";   




                                    }
                                }
                                echo "</select>";

echo "</td>";
```

Comment: Why don't you just display the options in a list then?

Comment: You can add a collapse/expand thing to show more items if you want to save space

Comment: List is shown all the time. It only needs to be displayed when user clicks on it, specially on mobile platform.

Comment: Read my second comment!

Comment: Works brilliantly, many thanks. Guessed there must be an easier solution.

Comment: i should've added it as an answer! points.. ;) ah well ..

Comment: While the javascript toggle works fine for one entry, when there are more than one row of data, it always displays the 1st one, i.e. first line, even the others are clicked to reveal the hidden list.

Comment: That's a small bug in the js. Post it as a question. (I can't answer now, off to a wedding!)

Comment: I have. Have a nice time.